# Best way to give a user some root privileges in particular apach files and command

Tags: webserver, privileges, hosts, apache-virtualhost

I wrote a shell script ([this one](http://cxg.de/_2931ac.html)) to init a new website project. It have to be executed by a user (it isn’t a mater if he got root privileges because this user is me).

As you see, the user have to be able to:

1. edit `/etc/hosts`;
2. Add new files to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`;
3. Create a new directory (with ln) in `/var/www/`;
4. Execute `a2ensite` command;
5. Execute `service  apache2 reload` command;

All this actions need to be executed as root. But is it possible to give rights to do this to a regular user?
And for this, have I to change owner of this files or the user’s group or both and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is normally done using `sudo`.  On modern systems you can add a file to `/etc/sudoers.d` adding new privileges.

```
# Rules for running am apache script.
User_Alias APACHE = yourUser
Cmnd_Alias APACHE = /usr/local/sbin/your_script
APACHE ALL = NOPASSWD: APACHE
```

Given that you are the user, you may want to add your account to the group defined in `/etc/sudoers` for administrators.  On Debian or Ubuntu systems this is `admin`.  Other distributions use different values.  This is the Ubuntu definition for the admin group.

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

`sudo` comes with detailed man pages.  You may want to review the man pages for `sudo`, `sudoers` and `visudo`.  If you have the man pages indexed, you can get a list of sudo related man pages with the command `man -k sudo`.